# How do i get the data from dbf format file?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, dbf

I am using Java in **NetBeans** to develop a program where i need to retrieve data from the few list of database file which is in 'dbf' format. I normally open the 'dbf' file with Microsoft Excel then import to Microsoft Access but this time i need all the process happen inside the code and will it possible to use query to get the data as well ?

Comment: Check out this Java library: https://github.com/jamel/dbf

Comment: It doesn't have query .. my database have more than 1000 data inside.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way is to import DBF tables into SQL database (H2, SQLite, PostgreSQL) and do any queries you need. Check this library [github.com/Yasas/xbase4j](https://github.com/Yasas/xbase4j) and/or contact me for examples.

Comment: Just pulled this off of github and I ran it against a DBF file on Java 1.8 and pulls the data great!